# Drupal 6 overriding a modules Block template files

Tags: templates, drupal, drupal-6, themes, overriding

I built a module called ap_news and it creates a few blocks. I have my custom block template files in "sites/all/modules/custom/ap_news/theme/". It all works but I want the designers to be able to override these tpl files by putting a copy of them in  "sites/mysite.com/themes/theme428/templates/block"  or in "sites/mysite.com/themes/theme428/templates/ap_news"
So I'd like Drupal to look in the sites theme folder first and if it doesn't find it, then look in my modules theme folder. I tried it but it only uses the one in my module.
Here is my block and theme code:

```
    function ap_news_block($op = 'list', $delta = 0, $edit = array()) {

    switch ($op) {

        case "list":

            // Generate listing of blocks from this module, for the admin/block page
            $block = array();
            $block['ap_news_national_news']['info'] = t('National news');
            $block['ap_news_national_news']['cache']=BLOCK_NO_CACHE;

            $block['ap_news_world_news']['info'] = t('World news');
            $block['ap_news_world_news']['cache']=BLOCK_NO_CACHE;           

            return $block;
            break;

        case "view":  

            switch ($delta) {

                case 'ap_news_national_news': // block-ap_news_national_news.tpl.php
                // Generate our block content       
                $html = ap_news_nationalNews();
                $block['subject'] = 'National News';  
                $block['content'] =  $html;
                $data = new stdClass(); $data->module = 'ap_news'; $data->content = $html; $data->delta = $delta; $data->subject = 'National News';
                $block['content'] =  theme('block-'.$delta, $data);
                break;
                //--------------------

                case 'ap_news_world_news': // block-ap_news-world_news.tpl.php
                $data = ap_news_allNews_block('WORLD', APNEWS_CID_WORLD_NEWS, 4);
                $block['subject'] = 'World News';
                $block['content'] =  theme('block-ap_news-all_news', $data, base_path().APNEWS_PATH_WORLD_NEWS, 'World News', 'worldNews');
                break;

            }

    }

    return $block;
}



function ap_news_theme() {

    return array(

        'block-ap_news-all_news' => array(
            'template' => 'theme/block-ap_news-all_news',
            'arguments' => array('data' => NULL, 'path' => NULL, 'sectionName' => NULL, 'sectionId' => NULL),
        ),
        'block-ap_news_national_news' => array(
            'template' => 'theme/block-ap_news_national_news',
            'arguments' => array('block' => NULL),
        ),

    );

}
```

---

**UPDATE:**
I have created a function for now to look for the files.

```
        'block-ap_news-national_news' => array(
        'template' => 'block-ap_news-national-news',
        'arguments' => array('block' => NULL),
        'path' => ap_news_templatePath('block', 'block-ap_news-national-news', 'ap_news'),
    ),

/*
 * Find the template paths. 
 * First look in the sites custom theme template folder (/themes/theme428/templates/ap_news), 
 * then in sites normal theme template folder, 
 * then in the modules folder
 */
function ap_news_templatePath($type, $template, $custom=''){

    $siteThemePath = path_to_theme() . '/templates/' . $type. '/';
    $siteCustomThemePath = path_to_theme() . '/templates/' . $custom. '/';
    $moduleThemePath = drupal_get_path('module', 'ap_news') . '/theme/';

    if(file_exists($siteCustomThemePath . $template . '.tpl.php')){
      return $siteCustomThemePath;
    }elseif(file_exists($siteThemePath . $template . '.tpl.php')){ 
        return $siteThemePath;
    }else{
        return $moduleThemePath;
    }

}
```

Comment: Could you post your `hook_theme()` implementation for the block theme(s) as well? Also, which Drupal version?

Comment: I'm using Drupal 6.20. I have the hook_theme in my original post, unless I'm missing something. I didn't know I needed a separate theme hook for my blocks. What am I missing? Thanks

Comment: Sorry, I somehow did not notice the `hook_theme()` code at first sight.

Answer (score 2):

On problem is that you prepend the modules 'theme' folder to the template name, which will mess up drupals template suggestion lookup functionality - you should use the 'path' element for that, e.g.:

```
function ap_news_theme() {
  $path_to_templates = drupal_get_path('module', 'ap_news') . '/theme';
  return array(
    'block-ap_news-all_news' => array(
      'template' => 'block-ap_news-all_news',
      'arguments' => array('data' => NULL, 'path' => NULL, 'sectionName' => NULL, 'sectionId' => NULL),
      'path' => $path_to_templates,
    ),
    'block-ap_news_national_news' => array(
      'template' => 'block-ap_news_national_news',
      'arguments' => array('block' => NULL),
      'path' => $path_to_templates,
    ),
  );
}
```

With this, it should still find the template files in your module, but overriding them from the theme folder should work.

**However**, I'm not sure if it would also find them in your proposed additional theme subfolders ('templates/ap_news' and 'templates/block'), so you should first test with the overrides placed directly in the theme (and the themes 'templates') folder directly.

Comment: Oups, forgot to actually remove the 'theme/' prefix in my answers example - fixed now.

Comment: Thanks Henrik. It's kind of working now, but when the file is not there (in "path_to_theme().'/templates/block")It throws an error about the file does not exist. I need it to look in the module folder if it can't find it in the main sites theme folder.

Comment: @EricP: Hmm, it _should_ just work with the fixed example above, but you _might_ face an additional problem with a naming convention clash, as your template names match the ones Drupal uses as potential template overrides to theme the 'view' output of your `hook_block` implementation. So you might want to try again using a different naming scheme for your 'inner' block theming than your current 'block-[delta]' version (which matches the one Drupal uses for the 'outer' `theme('block', ...)` call).

Comment: I updated my original post. I have created a function for now to look for the files. I'll try renaming them with a different naming convention later, but for now this is working for me.